# Ruby gems helper method (permitted_to?) in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I am using `declarative_authorization`. I want to use `permitted_to?` method in `rails console`. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `helper` object from your rails console:

```
helper.permitted_to?
```

This will give you access to all view helpers in your application (both, rails built in view helpers as well as helpers from any gem you might be using)

Comment: it is latest rails `3.2.21`

Comment: It works in context of `current_user`, better you can use `user.permitted_to?`  instance on console. That is alternate option,